# How to create KeyboardEvent using Typescript in IE and PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, testing, phantomjs, keyboard-events

I am using Angular2 and have a method that takes a KeyboardEvent object. I would like to write tests for this method (using Karma and Jasmine if that matters).

I wrote some using the KeyboardEvent constructor which worked fine in Chrome, but fails in IE and PhantomJS. Is there a way to do it that will work in these browsers?

Method signature:

```
public onDateKeypress(evt: KeyboardEvent): boolean {
    // ...
}
```

Current test example:

```
let ke = new KeyboardEvent("keypress", { "key": "" + i, });
onDateKeypress(ke);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I ended up with, I'm open to better solutions.

```
let ke = <KeyboardEvent>{ "key": "" + i, };
onDateKeypress(ke);
```

**Explanation**:
The typescript code will be compiled down to Javascript and the Javascript doesn't care what "type" the data is, only that the object has the correct properties/methods on it.

In my case the onDateKeypress method only uses the "key" propertyof the evt param, so that's all I need to set on my test object.

Casting the annonymous object to Keyboard event is required so that the Typescript will compile without complaining, since the method expects an object of type KeyboardEvent.

Comment: any idea why this works, im new to this space and got burned yesterday thinking all my tests were passing (running Chrome locally), ended up breaking the build which runs in Phantom :)

Comment: @GaryO'Donoghue I have edited the answer with an explanation. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Thank you for that, would you mind clarifying why using the ‘new KeyboardEvent’ approach causes issues though, I would have thought this accomplishes the same thing, it almost seems like a flaw in the constructor that it hasn’t set the ‘key’ property properly, or something which Phantom handles differently somehow

Comment: @GaryO'Donoghue I believe it's just that the constructor isn't implemented in Phantom (or IE), the same way many newer features aren't implemented in every browser.